# transforming random.random uniform to exponential distribution doesn't produce correct result

Tags: python, random

I am trying to generate a synthetic earthquake database where the number of events ($N$) with magnitude ($M$) in the range $[M, M+\delta_M]$ follows:
$\log_{10}(N) = a - bM$
where $a$ and $b$ are constants.

I am trying to do this in Python using the `random` module. I know I can (or at least I think I can - as I haven't tried it) use `random.expovariate` but I thought I could use `random.random` with a transformation like:

```
-math.log10(random.random()))
```

I ran this for 2,000,000 samples which I then binned into 0.1 bins and plotted on a log scale.

[image]

The red line shows the theoretical distribution used to generate the synthetic samples.

I'm not worried about the variation above x=4.5. This is due to small number of points and natural randomness. What I am asking about is the very small (at this scale) variation for the points near x=0. I plotted the variation of the synthetic points from the theoretical (blue dots):

[image: diff between observed and theory]

As x decreases the number of events increase exponentially so the variation from the theoretical should decrease - not increase. And the point at x=0 is the opposite sense.

To try and work out where my problem lies I wrote code that generated numbers from 0 to 1 with a very fine step. Each number then went through the function noted above. The result (the blue dots in the above figure) is purely linear that exactly matches the theoretical values. This indicates that my transformation function and code is fine.

So the only difference between the twp sets of points in the above figure is that the blue ones are generated by 2,000,000 calls to the random function (results are then transformed into magnitudes and binned), while for the red ones I've taken 2,000,000 uniform steps between 0 and 1 (results are then transformed into magnitudes and binned using the same code).

So I'm thinking it's somehow something to do with the random number generator?

Would be grateful for any pointers. Thanks.

[added]
Changed the call from random.random to `random.uniform(0,1)` as suggested by @Arty and the errors are now symmetrically distributed and of the expected magnitude. Have added +- 1 standard deviation to the plot.

[image: deviation from expected +- 1 standard deviation]

Clearly `random()` and `uniform(0,1)` are doing something slightly differently.

---

I cut down my code and calculated synthetic data using `random.random`, `random.uniform(0,1)`, `np.random.random` and `np.random.uniform(0, 1)` for 2,000,000 points.

Binned the results and plotted the difference between the observed and expected numbers (below).

[image]

Also added in the +-1 standard deviation limits. The numbers are all symmetrically distributed and of the correct magnitude indicating that ALL the random generators are working fine.

My conclusion is that somewhere along the line of changing/refining code I introduced a problem which has now been lost. I would dearly like to find that error so I don't make it again!

I am surprised that my original, incorrect code could perform correctly to the extent that it generated a real looking synthetic with only minor anomalies that were difficult to detect.

Thanks for everyone's help and apologies to those I disagreed with that said the problem did not lie with the random number generators!

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE] that shows how you performed the generation, accumulation, and binning? I figure the two most probable causes would be denormal numbers (providing a greater range of possible values near 0; I haven't thought it through enough to be sure that's a real possibility) or a bug in the binning, but it would help to see the code.

Comment: Can you possible also test randomness of [np.random.uniform(0, 1)](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html) with your code? It uses different algorithm and code for generation. Interesting if it will give same results as `random.random()`. Also nice if you provide whole code that did this graphs and measurements.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @Arty. Have modifed the question. So something about the random() call is dodgy. Getting late here so will look again tomorrow.

Comment: Can you please clearly define what you mean by variation, and ideally most other things translating to mathematical formulas? These terms are not always the same across domains and frameworks. Since the sampling is exponential, plotting the variance logarithmically might also show if the bias is *just* from the translation of linear to exponential. Note that overall, this might be more appropriate to the math/statistics stackexchange than [so].

Comment: I tried math/stats stackexchange - Did not get much help.

Comment: @RustyC Okay. But please be aware that this is very, very likely a statistical problem – including the features of the various random distributions. Even by taking your comparison as the *uniform* sample you already introduce a bias, which might not be what you actually want. Your binning is biased towards uniform, but the data is biased towards small values (that is, data in the bins is not centered and not uniform). [so] is appropriate to figure out why ``random.random`` deviates from the uniform distribution, but not to warn you if a uniform distribution is not suitable for the problem.

Comment: @RustyC Can you also do some comments on Daniel's [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64676971/941531) if he is right or wrong? Seems that your function in fact should behave non-uniformly for different `X` value. So it could be that you made wrong assumptions regarding variance and distribution of your function.

Comment: @RustyC Also can you please measure in your code totally another random number generator implementation which NumPy has? Just use [np.random.uniform(0, 1)](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html) function. If it will give same "wrong" results on your graphs then it definitely means that you made some wrong assumptions on what you should expect on your graphs, because if different implementations of random number have same "wrong" behavior then probably you're wrong not them.

Comment: I don't see how [`random.uniform(0,1)`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/random.py#L503) can affect things, it'll just evaluate `0 + 1 * random.random()` so should just be a bit slower

Comment: @SamMason My assumption is that this is just pile-up effects from a different random seed.

Comment: @RustyC As you already did measurement on `np.random.uniform()` can you explain your graph now and make conslusion? Is `np.random.uniform()` "better" than `random.random()`? Also is it what you want? Or still both of functions give "wrong" results that you don't like for your use case?

Comment: @RustyC you say "Clearly random() and uniform(0,1) are doing something slightly differently." but I've linked to the CPython code and we can see it doesn't do anything differently

Comment: @MisterMiyagi being 18k out is much more than expected variance, standard deviation of that first bin should be ~650 (i.e. `sqrt((1-10**-0.1) * 2e6)`).  I'd assume OP is doing binning incorrectly

Comment: @Arty - I'll cut down code and use random.random, random.uniform(0,1), np.random and np.random.uniform(0, 1) to see how they compare.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi - Can't see how it can be the binning as all I've changed in the two runs is the random call. As I said above, I'll combine all the calls in the one lot of code.

Comment: @RustyC thanks for the follow up!  the subtle code effects you're talking about is why we suggest including a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  it reduces a lot of ambiguity around questions.  it might be worth adding the code you used to produce the final plot as an answer to your question, i.e. to show other people how to do this

Answer (score 2):

Initially I thought you might be having some numerical analysis problem.  Trying a million samples in python, however, I get the following observed results:

```
>>> T = int(1e6)
>>> xs = [ -math.log10(random.random()) for i in range(T)]
>>> len([x for x in xs if 0 <= x < 0.1])
205614
>>> len([x for x in xs if 0.1 <= x < 0.2])
163736
>>> len([x for x in xs if 0.2 <= x < 0.3])
129627
>>> len([x for x in xs if 0.3 <= x < 0.4])
103413
>>> len([x for x in xs if 0.4 <= x < 0.5])
81734
```

If X = -log_10(x) with x uniformly distributed on [0, 1), then we should have

```
P(M <= X < M + d) = P(-M-d < log_10(x) <= -M) = 10^(-M) - 10^(-M-d)
```

and the numbers above are basically perfectly in line with these probabilities, e.g.

```
1 - 10^(-0.1) = 0.205672
```

which matches up nicely with our observed 205614 out of a million trials above.

Do you get different results than I do for the python code above?

Comment: So what is your consolusion? Is `random.random()` OK or not? Also can you do same measurements for `np.random.uniform(0., 1.)` if not to difficult? These two functions should have different implementations of random generators.

Comment: @Arty: I believe that `random.random` is working as documented on my machine, and that moreover the documented behavior makes it a perfectly good approximation of true randomness for OP's purposes.  Since the OP hasn't specified in detail what the graphs in the question depict, I can't say any more about that.  As for the `numpy` random generators, I imagine that they're not worse than the builtin python ones.

Comment: Incidentally, if one "Changed the call from random.random to random.uniform(0,1)" the result basically does not change at all – not surprising seeing how ``random.uniform`` just scales the result of ``random.random``.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi - But it has changed the results!

Comment: @Daniel McLaury - Ran you code and I get:
205777
163508
129735
103058
82295
Essentially same as you - within expected random variation.